# CoreML - Cannot perform conversion from Keras to CoreML - Windows 10

Tags: keras, theano, coreml

I recently upgraded my `keras` from version `1.1.0` to `1.2.2` and I ran a CNN for hand gesture classification (the code was developed using `keras 1.1.0`). I saved the trained model and I tried to convert it to `CoreML` model using `coremltools`. The code is as shown below:

```
import coremltools
import theano
from keras import backend as K
K.set_image_dim_ordering('th')

coreml_model = coremltools.converters.keras.convert('hgm_2.h5')
coreml_model.save('hgm.mlmodel')
```

But it gave me the following error:

```
RuntimeError: keras not found or unsupported version or backend found. keras conversion API is disabled.
```

How can I fix this issue? I tried upgrading `theano`, but it gave the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have received a reply [here](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/81085). Currently the conversion is not supported for `theano` backend.